# Is there something like django's contenttypes framework for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I am new to rails but have developed a lot of apps in django. Django provides a contenttypes framework that creates a table with unique ids for each model allowing objects from multiple tables can be referenced using the `object id` and the `content-type id`. ([more info on the contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/))

This is very helpful as now I can have just one table for something like votes instead of having as many tables as the number of things that can be voted (like `question_votes`, `answer_votes`, `comment_votes`, `post_votes`). Also, if something new type that need voting like `blogs` come along you don't have to go about creating a new table `blog_votes`. So this makes life easy.

My question is, is there a framework/gem that does the same for rails?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter already noted, probably You want a polymorphic associations. Consider this example:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end
```

More info here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 1):

[Polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) solving this problem